# What is the vite-plugin-string alternative for Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to add a shader to an already existing "Three" Sphere, however, I do not know which plugin I should use to store the file into a variable on nuxt.

I do know this one for Vite: https://github.com/aweikalee/vite-plugin-string

Comment: I recommend you to look into [Webpack file loader](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets/#webpack) system, this will basically say that for a given file extension, what should be used and how.